# how to compare values inside a list with each other in c#

Tags: c#, list

any one to help me solving this problem of mine? 
I want to find biggest value inside a list inserted by keyboard something like this:

here it can be done by array:

```
        int[] values = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = (int) (textbox.Text);
        }
        //to campare them
        int bigValue=0;
        for(int j=0;j<values.Lenght;j++)
        {
          if(bigValue<values[j])
           { 
             bigValue==values[j];
           } 
         }
        ////////////////////////////////
```

but in my code I have to use List I have filled the list but now I don't know the way to compare its values with each other to find the lowest and biggest one:

```
        List<int> values= new List<int>();
        values.Add((int)(textbox.Text));
```

Comment: And what's the problem you're having with the code that you already have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres already built in functions for it, [Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb909383%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [Min](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb919785(v=vs.90).aspx):

```
int maxValue = values.Max();
int minValue = values.Min();
```

Your *original* function would work as well, substituting `Count` for `Length`, as indexing works with lists as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ `Min` & `Max` functions:-

```
int LowestNumber = values.Min();
int HighestNumber = values.Max();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you say you also need to use the list later in your program I guess you could find useful just to have it sorted.

```
values.Sort((value1, value2) => value1.CompareTo(value2));
```

With this option, minValue would be values[0] although the recomended way to find it is using the built in function as they have already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You could just say something like this, which will work for any `IEnumerable<int>`, whether it's an `int[]`, a `List<int>` or something else:

```
int? max = null ;
foreach( int value in someList )
{
  max = (max??value) > value : (max??value) ;
}
```

At the end of this, If the list was empty, `max` will be `null`; otherwise `max` will have the highest value in the list.